# How to rotate portrait/landscape Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to Android development.
I know if you change a android phone from portrait to landscape sometimes the app relays its self out on the screen.. so how do I simulate rotating a phone with the emulator? 
On the Blackberry emulators there's a button in the menu to turn the phone, but I can't find it or any option on the Android ones?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

See the Android documentation on [controlling the emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling); it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

On ThinkPad running Ubuntu, you may try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow Key</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow Key</kbd>

Comment: on mac: fn+control+F11 or fn+control+f12

Comment: It rotates, but if you design a view to work on both portrait and landscape, the app wont be rotated, only the windows, so its like you rotate your phone 90 degrees but the app keeps in portrait mode.

Comment: @MateusViccari That's a bug in the Android 4.4 emulator image. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4. Other emulator images should work fine.

Comment: @YoniSamlan, Right Ctrl button doesn't work. Only left works.

Answer (score 92):

Officially it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>KEYPAD 7</kbd> & <kbd>KEYPAD 9</kbd>.

In practise it's a bit quirky.

1. Specifically it's <kbd>**Left** Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>**Left** Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to switch to previous orientation and next orientation respectively.
2. <s>You have to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> before you can rotate again.</s>
3. <kbd>KEYPAD 7</kbd> and <kbd>KEYPAD 9</kbd> only work with <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> **OFF** (so they're acting as <kbd>Home</kbd> & <kbd>PageUp</kbd> rather than <kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>9</kbd>).
4. The **only orientations** are vertically upright and rotated one quarter-turn anti-clockwise.

Maybe a bit too much info for such a simple question, but it drove me half-mad finding this out.

Note: This was tested on Android SDK R16 and a very old keyboard, modern keyboards may behave differently.

Comment: Again thank you for your answer, but this question was asked (and resolved) in 2010 !

Comment: @Bex I just had some frustration to vent (thanks to the quirks listed), so I channelled it into a post.

Comment: May help someone then. Can't say I have these problems though!

Comment: @Bex: Yes, and Andrew added some great details that weren't in the original answer of just a link. Stack Overflow is about creating useful and lasting artifacts on the Internet, so thanks to Andrew for improving the internet!

Comment: This is still the same. **This should be the accepted answer!** I don't get why it's so quirky. I was pressing the right-Ctrl and it didn't work at all! Normally, applications shouldn't distinguish between the two control keys - that kind of distinguishing is reserved for video games and specialized applications! And having to release the Ctrl key is just ridiculous.

Comment: Only the numpad works for me.

Comment: Numpad => It works for me **only** with **Num Lock** set to **ON**. If it's off does not work for me. For the rest, answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 35):

Yes. Thanks

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for Portrait

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> for Landscape

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this question was resolved about a year ago!

Comment: @Bex: Yes, but it is always nice to have more information added to the answer. Anshuman is more clean in saying which keys for which orientation, which Yoni didn't mention.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth, That should have been an **edit** on the original post. Not a new post.

Comment: @Pacerier It is fine with me if you want to edit it as such.