# Rotate android emulator display

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I rotate emulator display (not the complete emulator) because my Honeycomb display is tilted 90<sup>o</sup>.

I tried pressing `Ctrl + F12`, `Num 7` and `9`, but the complete emulator is shown in portrait mode. I need to tilt only the display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android Emulator Shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

Ctrl+F12 Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

1. Main Device Keys

<kbd>Home</kbd> Home Button

<kbd>F2</kbd> Left Softkey / Menu / Settings button (or <kbd>Page up</kbd>)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Right Softkey / Star button (or <kbd>Page down</kbd>)

<kbd>Esc</kbd> Back Button

<kbd>F3</kbd> Call/ dial Button

<kbd>F4</kbd> Hang up / end call button

<kbd>F5</kbd> Search Button

1. Other Device Keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Volume up (or <kbd>+</kbd> on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> Volume down (or <kbd>+</kbd> on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) <kbd>F7</kbd> Power Button <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> Camera Button

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

<kbd>F8</kbd> Toggle cell network

<kbd>F9</kbd> Toggle code profiling

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Toggle fullscreen mode

<kbd>F6</kbd> Toggle trackball mode

Answer (score 1):

You can change orientation of the emulator using `left ctrl+F11` key .

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>  to change the orientation of the android emulator on windows

Comment: Make sure you say "left ctrl+F11".  Otherwise it doesn't work for me.  I am on a Win8 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just screen cannot be tilted. Phone itself turns to landscape and followed be screen rotation.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator?rq=1) for more help.

Comment: But I don't know I unknowingly pressed some keys before and the display got tilted, and now I'm not able to revert it back.

Answer (score 0):

on your activity:-

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or

on your manifest:-

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"  
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Comment: its not the application display which is tilted, its the emulator display(Honeycomb home screen).

Comment: have u see this link before asking question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916096/android-avd-rotate-portrait-landscape-how>

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

please check your `manifest.xml`. suppose you gave screenOrientation please remove it.

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: its not the application which is tilted, its the emulator display I mean Honeycomb home screen.

Comment: is your emulator is rotated? when u press 7 in your keyboard.And also cneck your num lock is open

Comment: This does not fix the issue if the emulator is up side down. This will rotate the display 90 degrees only