# Rotate Android Virtual Device AVD using hotkey

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I can't rotate the android's AVD using the shortcuts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator/36161682#36161682),[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-do-i-rotate-the-android-emulator-display), [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916096/how-to-rotate-portrait-landscape-android-emulator)
I've tried:   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
 NumPad On/Off <kbd>7</kbd> / <kbd>9</kbd> and other options from the above links.
Does anyone know what else can I try?
  Just a note: I don't want to click in the side options, I am looking for keyboard shortcut only. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some version of Android emulator (recently, like 27.0.0 or so) it is possible to restart the emulator with Ctrl key (Ctrl for Mac) + left arrow or right arrow.
So:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> OR <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>).

You can also modify the shortcuts in here:

[image: Emulator Options]

Comment: Is there a hotkey to reset scale/zoom? It isn't listed but I'm pretty sure I "accidently" pressed it sometime and since the scale up/down hotkeys does not say the actual scale it's difficult to know when you're back to "default". I know that the scale is a bit difficult to represent on a screen due to pixel density and whatnot but still - I'd like to reset the default scale with a hotkey.